# How does Angular2 know which component corresponds to the template?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In the tour of heros tutorial the `app.component.ts` code looks like this:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    export class Hero {
      id: number;
      name: string;
    }

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
        <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
        <div>
          <label>name: </label>
          <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
        </div>
        `
    })


    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'Tour of Heros';
      hero: Hero = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Windstorm'
      };
    }
```

Does Angular2 assume that the class that comes after the `@component` declaration is the class that is responsible for creating the data used to populate the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Angular2 assume that the class that comes after the @component declaration is the class that is responsible for creating the data used to populate the template?

yeap, this is typescript spec:

> A Class Decorator is declared just before a class declaration. The
>   class decorator is applied to the constructor of the class and can be
>   used to observe, modify, or replace a class definition. A class
>   decorator cannot be used in a declaration file, or in any other
>   ambient context (such as on a declare class).

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators

Answer (score 1):

Yes - the @Component is a decorator on the class. From the angular docs:

> Component decorator allows you to mark a class as an Angular component and provide additional metadata that determines how the component should be processed, instantiated and used at runtime.

Read more [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html).